# Angular 2 Form Serialization Into JSON Format

Tags: json, forms, angular

I am having a little bit of trouble creating my Angular 2 form and converting the submitted data into JSON format for the use of submitting it to my API. I am looking for something that works very similarly to this example:
`$.fn.serializeObject = function()`
http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/
The only problem with this example is that the code is written in JQuery, whereas I'm trying to use strictly angular 2. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am still very new to angular.

Comment: if you are using angular then why there is no ngmodel in your input?

Comment: Because this was an example I found, not my code. I want to implement something similar to this example using angular 2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `getRawValue()` function if you're using a `FormGroup`, to return an object that can then be serialized using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fbuilder: FormBuilder,
                private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.form = this.fbuilder.group({
            name: '',
            description: ''
        });
    }

    sendToAPI(){
        let formObj = this.form.getRawValue(); // {name: '', description: ''}

        let serializedForm = JSON.stringify(formObj);

        this.http.post("www.domain.com/api", serializedForm)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log("success!", data),
                error => console.error("couldn't post because", error)
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `JSON.stringify(form.value)`:

```
submit() {
  let resource = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);

  console.log('Add Button clicked: ' + resource);

  this.service.create(resource)
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
}
```

Result in Chrome DevTools:
[image: Result of console.log]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `JSON.stringify(object)` which will give you the JSON represantation of your javascript object.

You can then POST this using the built-in HTTP service to your server.

Comment: FormGroups can, and usually do, contain circular references, so this solution would not work unless you customized the stringify function.