# Create JSON outputted data from Angular 2 form to be used in serverless contact form powered by AWS

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, contact-form, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ses

I am trying to write a contact form within Angular 2 that calls AWS API Gateway, supplying the user's email address/name/message in JSON format:

```
  {
      "email": "test@john.com",
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "message": "A test message"
    }
```

I have AWS API Gateway configured to receive the above JSON format and have AWS Lambda configured and tested to use AWS SES to send an email when the above JSON formatted data is received.  These parts of the chain are working.

I am very new to Angular 2, and, have created forms following examples, but am now lost in how to proceed to create the form and for it to JSON Stringify the output to my API gateway URL, and use HTTP service to send this data to my API gateway endpoint.

I wondered if someone could offer a fresh approach?

Many thanks everyone :)

Comment: do you need to send form data to specific URL path ?

Comment: Yes - I have created a specific AWS API gateway endpoint: https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod that I can receive the appropriate JSON formatted data.  I used this blog https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/ to set-up the API Gateway / Lambda, but, I am really struggling to work out how to write the Angular2 form to process the output as JSON and send to the API Gateway.  I am learning forms, but, cannot find anything to follow specific to creating the JSON and POSTing it to the invoke URL.

Comment: I have tried using the code from [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698247/angular-2-form-serialization-into-json-format[/link]

Comment: which I have amended to a new component with FormGroup and FormBuilder added to my app.module, but, I am getting "Unexpected value 'FormGroup' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation." error from the console - even though I have added both FormGroup and FormBuilder to the declarations.  Any ideas please anyone???  I really just want to get a functioning form creating JSON and sending to my API that I can learn from :)

Comment: import FormGroup and FormBuilder instead of declaring them.please add your codes if you need further clarifications.

Comment: json-form.component.ts - it won't let me add the code - it says "too long by 354 characters...." - so I'll post it in three messages...

Comment: `export class JsonFormComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fbuilder: FormBuilder,
                private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.form = this.fbuilder.group({
            name: '',
            description: ''
        });
    }`

Comment: `sendToAPI(){
        let formObj = this.form.getRawValue(); // {name: '', description: ''}

        let serializedForm = JSON.stringify(formObj);

        this.http.post("www.domain.com/api", serializedForm)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log("success!", data),
                error => console.error("couldn't post because", error)
            );
    }
}`

Comment: `@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    JsonFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormGroup,
    FormBuilder,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
`

Comment: make a plunker(https://plnkr.co/) and post the URL in question. you dont need to post it as three comments.you can edit the question and add other codes there

Comment: Struggling a bit to get a default angular 2 / 4 plunker set-up and make this work.  Plunker is only offering AngularJS 1.5x maximum - no angular 2 or 4

Comment: Could anyone offer some example code please?  I've been struggling now following many examples and just can't get this to work.  I'd love just to work through a 'working example' of code to learn.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Got a wonderful answer from this question:

[Create a Contact form in Angular 2 / 4 that POSTS JSON to a specified API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427843/create-a-contact-form-in-angular-2-4-that-posts-json-to-a-specified-api)

Please try the plunker also: it answers the question perfectly :)

BIG thanks to @Tiep Phan for a very thorough and quick reply.