# Create a Contact form in Angular 2 / 4 that POSTS JSON to a specified API

Tags: angular, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create an Angular 2 / 4 project that has a 'Contact Us' form that creates data via JSON.stringify to then POST to my API that I have setup in AWS API Gateway.  This uses Lambda and SES to email the details to me.

I am struggling learning Angular 2 / 4 and an working example of such type of form would be a terrific learning tool to amend and learn from.

I have followed many Angular 2 example videos and read tutorials, but, I'm unable to find a simple form that POSTs JSON to an API to follow/amend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated folks! :)

Comment: I'm hoping to POST data to my API in the following JSON format:

Comment: `{
 "email": "john.smith@email.com",
 "name": "John Smith",
 "phone": "123-456-7890",
 "message": "I'd like to know more please?"
}`

Comment: The post I followed to get my AWS-Lambda / SES / AWS API Gateway working was: [link]https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/

Comment: My API endpoint format is: [link]https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/rest/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form in Angular is powerful and easy to use.
Let's build a simple form with Reactive Form.

**1:** We grab all NgModule we need to use Reactive Form and call AJAX with Http:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpModule, // for http request
    ReactiveFormsModule // for form system
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**2:** And our AppComponent look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FromGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="frmContact" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
      <div>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" formControlName="name">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Comment:
          <textarea formControlName="content"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button [disabled]="frmContact.invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div *ngIf="res">
      Response:
      <pre>{{ res | json }}</pre>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  frmContact: FormGroup;
  private _sub;

  res: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.frmContact = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      content: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let formValue = this.frmContact.value;
    // cool stuff to transform form value

    // call AJAX

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // clean subscription when component destroy
    if (this._sub) {
      this._sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

We inject FormBuilder class to AppComponent to create our form when Component Init.

And we use `Validators` to use pre-built Validator function - `required` for example.

In component template, we use some directive `formGroup`, `formControlName` to bind our form to template.

**3:** Now, we need a service to communicate with server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  private API_ENDPOINT = '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; //replace with your API ENDPOINT
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  saveContact(contact: any) {
    return this._http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT, contact)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Maybe in some case, you need include Header (Authorization token, for example), you need create header like this:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // create new Headers object with header Content-Type is application/json.
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + your_token); //JWT token
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

And send request with header:

```
saveContact(contact: any) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // create new Headers object with header Content-Type is application/json.
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + your_token); //JWT token
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this._http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT, contact, options)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**4:** Update AppComponent and AppModule to use service

**AppModule**

```
// other import
import { PostService } from './post.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    //...
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ PostService ], // declare our service into this array
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**AppComponent**

```
// other import

import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Component({
  //...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  frmContact: FormGroup;
  private _sub;

  res: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private postService: PostService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //...
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let formValue = this.frmContact.value;
    // cool stuff to transform form value

    // call AJAX
    this._sub = this.postService.saveContact(formValue)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.res = data;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // clean subscription when component destroy
    if (this._sub) {
      this._sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

When user click to button submit, `onSubmit` method will execute, then it'll call service method `this.postService.saveContact` to send your data.

You can play with Live Demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/GCYsGwreHi13FejcWDtE?p=preview

Document: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: Firstly, I went to your plunker and modified it with my API endpoint, forked it (hopefully - plunker is new to me) here: [link]https://plnkr.co/edit/ck7P2qFqFtp8sZJdwVVd?p=preview

Comment: could you describe your API input

Comment: but it didn't work, and, I'm unable to troubleshoot due to my lack of experience.  Please could you give me any pointers how best to troubleshoot?  I know that I'll have to change the form fields - the API is tested with the JSON file I mentioned at the top of this post

Comment: for my API input, I used your plunker and changed the API endpoint to my own: I added a test name and comments and then pressed 'submit'

Comment: As I can see, you need include `Authentication Token` to able to send request to your endpoint

Comment: Is that within the Angular code or at the AWS end please?  How did you troubleshoot that please?

Comment: Just got a successful API POST to email from you @Tiep Phan!!!!!!  I'm ecstatic :)

Comment: But how did you achieve it please?

Comment: please refer this document, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html and enable `cors` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html. here is update version https://plnkr.co/edit/WwJQzrE154h7T5m7NRSS?p=preview . when enable cors, you could remove `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`.

Comment: I'm added one more header `headers.append('Auth', 'allow');`, you could create other token then replace with value above

Comment: Thank you so much @Tiep Phan  this has been such a blocker and I am so pleased that you have helped me move it forward.  I really appreciate your help :)  btw do you ever work as a freelancer?

Comment: Mostly, I can work less than 30 hours per week. feel free to contact me.

Comment: This is my email `phan.t.tiep@gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks again @Tiep Phan - I'll email you later :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: One last question please @Tiep Phan:  please could you show me how to turn the response code into boolean that I could use to present a red/green button for email send success or fail?  `<div *ngIf="res">
      Response:
      <pre>{{ res | json }}</pre>
    </div>`

Comment: BTW - hope you got my email today? Thank you sincerely once again for all your help :)

Comment: if you wanna access all response properties - include some thing like **code** you can remove this line in saveContact in post service "map(res => res.json())". sorry, I am online on mobile right now, I can not update code above. And I got your email, I'll reply soon.